# Tooltip Bootstrap 3 sumir quando eu clicar em outro

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Eu tenho 3 tooltips. Quero que eles apareçam no click, então usei o seguinte:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        trigger : 'click'
    });
```

Assim, quando eu clico no primeiro, por exemplo, ele exibe o tooltip.

Porém, quero que quando eu clique em um tooltip ele ative o mesmo e desative os outros que estiverem ativos.

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Comment: Separe a sua chamada do Tooltip por id do botão. Assim você garante que apenas um seja chamado.

Comment: Pode mostrar um exemplo seguindo o caso de eu ter 3 tooltips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue uma outra *alternativa* de solução, mostrando os tooltips **manualmente**

Sempre que o evento de click de um elemento que tem tooltip é acionado, esconde todos os tooltips visíveis e mostra somente o tooltip do elemento clicado.

Segue um fiddle com um exemplo funcional: https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/rha7ppu7/5/

Comment: Resolveu meu problema, funcionou perfeitamente ;) +100 Abraços

Answer (score 4):

Você deve fechar todos os outros tooltips e abrir apenas o que clicou.

Com este html:

```
<a class="btn"  rel='popover' data-placement='bottom' data-original-title='Teste 1' data-toggle='tooltip'>Um</a>
<a class="btn" rel='popover' data-placement='right' data-original-title='Teste 2' data-toggle='tooltip'>Dois</a>
```

Bastaria apenas essa chamada para se comportar como citou:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger: 'click'});

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').not(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

Segue link de exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/vFDSZ/526/

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo!